# Add delay to jQuery AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Is there a way to add a delay to my type of AutoComplete search function? I basically only want my php search to initiate when the user finishes typing (1 second delay).

Here's my jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
    /* Get input value on change */
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length > 1){
      $.get("search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
        // Display the returned data in browser
        resultDropdown.html(data);
      });
    } else{
      resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });
  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a timeout

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
      /* Get input value on change */
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
      if(inputVal.length > 1){
        setTimeout(function(){$.get("search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
            // Display the returned data in browser
            resultDropdown.html(data);
          });}, 1000);
        } else{
          resultDropdown.empty();
        }
      });
      
    });
```

Comment: This seems to work thanks! However it doesn't work perfectly. My dropdown flickers results, as though it is iterating through each keystroke after the timeout, it happens super quickly, but it looks quite ugly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    //do something special
  }, 5000);
This should make it work
```

if that didnt work for you try and do

> `$(selector).delay(para1, para2);`

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks! Perhaps this would solve the issue I'm having with Scais suggestion. But I'm not sure how I would implement your style with the code I'm using. Trying it now but it's not returning a result.